# 2000 Jeep Grand Cherokee Console not working

Tags: electrical, jeep, electronics, grand-cherokee, center-console

I am an owner of a 2000 Jeep Grand Cherokee. The roof console (the display attached to the center of the roof that normally displays compass direction and such) does not display anything. No idea what it could be. What could be the problem?

Comment: By console do you mean the instrument cluster, aka binnacle?

Comment: @GdD the display attached to the center of the roof that normally displays compass direction and such.